# Do celebrities/famous people get preferential treatment when convicted of crimes?

Tags: celebrities

It always seems odd that many famous people/celebrities seem to get off of crimes with barely a scratch or dent, yet ordinary people who get into trouble end up paying for it far longer than  others.

Is this true? Or am I just experiencing some confusion?

Comment: I think you'll find it's more related to being *rich* or powerful. Politicians get it even easier...

Comment: It's impossible to answer this meaningfully in its current form: how do we define "celebrity", "crime", "paying" and where is this claimed to happen? Is the question, for example, "do film actors go to jail for less years than the average person in Canada?" or "do musicians pay less driving fines than the average person in Italy?" or...

Comment: @Sklivvz - for a very obvious and meaningful example, drug law prosecution. How many entertainment industry celebrities ever gone to jail for posession or use? (vs nearly 100% of them doing drugs). Compare that to normal population.

Comment: @DVK for an even more obvious and significantly worse example, google for "affluenza" and experience horror as you realize that a judge seriously used that word to let some rich brat get away with DUI vehicular homicide.

Comment: @Shadur - first of all, [that wasn't the judge. It was a witness. The judge explicitly said that didn't influence her decision](http://www.cnn.com/2014/02/05/us/texas-affluenza-teen/). Second, that's an anecdote - despite my own personal preference that, like any drunk driver, that person be shot on the spot, I must point out that you need to show a **pattern**, not one case.